# I can't reset the image on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't reset the image on javascript, codepen say imagem in not defined.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/AlissonTelez/pen/ExPJBvv

Thats variables:

```
var originalImage;
var grayImage = null;
var redImage = null;
var rainbowImage = null;
var windowImage = null;
var canvas = document.getElementById("can1");
```

thats function to make filter red:

```
function makeRedy() {
  if (imgCarregada(imagemRedy)) {
    filtroVermelho();
    var canNovo = document.getElementById("can");
    imagemRedy.drawTo(canvas);
  }
}
function filtroVermelho() {
    for (var pixel2 of imagemRedy.values()) {
      avg2 = (pixel2.getRed()+pixel2.getGreen()+pixel2.getBlue()/3);
      if (avg2 < 128) {
        pixel2.setRed(2*avg2);
        pixel2.setGreen(0);
        pixel2.setBlue(0);
      }
      else {
        pixel2.setRed(255);
        pixel2.setGreen((2*avg2)-255);
        pixel2.setBlue((2*avg2)-255);
      }
   }
}
```

that's reset function:

```
function resete() {
  if (imgCarregada(imagem)) {
    imagem.drawTo(canvas);
  }
}
function imgCarregada(x) {
  if (x === null) {
    return false;
  }
  else if (x !== null) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your `resete` function, where does that function get the value for `imagem`? Don't see that variable defined anywhere else in the code.

Comment: you are right, @pai.not.pi , my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined `imagem`. But it appears your original image is being stored as `imagemOriginal`.

Change your `resete()` function to this;

```
function resete() {
  if (imgCarregada(imagemOriginal)) {
    imagemOriginal.drawTo(canvas);
  }
}
```

Based on your [CodePen](https://codepen.io/AlissonTelez/pen/ExPJBvv). Which appears to hold different values to what you pasted in your question.

Comment: You're welcome @AlissonTelez - simple mistake to make, simple one to fix :)

Answer (score 0):

read my comments in code and try understand what's new

```
// for checking later if null or not 
var imagemOriginal = null;
var imagemRedy = null;
var imagemGray = null;

var avg;
var avg2;

 // ctx for canvas api 2d
var canvas , ctx;


function upload() {
  var img = document.getElementById("Finput");
  
    
    canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    // defined canvas context 2d for drawing and accessing all canvas api
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  imagemOriginal = new SimpleImage(img);
  imagemGray = new SimpleImage(img);
  imagemRedy = new SimpleImage(img);
  imagemOriginal.drawTo(canvas);
}

// calling upload as first step for making canvas ready
upload();

function makeGray() {
  if (imgCarregada(imagemGray)) {
  filtroCinza();
  var canNovo = document.getElementById("can");
  imagemGray.drawTo(canvas);
  }
}

function filtroCinza() {
    for (var pixel of imagemGray.values()) {
    avg = (pixel.getRed()+pixel.getGreen()+pixel.getBlue())/3;
    pixel.setRed(avg);
    pixel.setGreen(avg);
    pixel.setBlue(avg);
  }
}

function makeRedy() {
  if (imgCarregada(imagemRedy)) {
  filtroVermelho();
  var canNovo = document.getElementById("can");
  imagemRedy.drawTo(canvas);
  }
}

function filtroVermelho() {
    for (var pixel2 of imagemRedy.values()) {
    avg2 = (pixel2.getRed()+pixel2.getGreen()+pixel2.getBlue()/3);
    if (avg2 < 128) {
      pixel2.setRed(2*avg2);
      pixel2.setGreen(0);
      pixel2.setBlue(0);
    }
    else {
      pixel2.setRed(255);
      pixel2.setGreen((2*avg2)-255);
      pixel2.setBlue((2*avg2)-255);
    }
   }
}

// in resete function you put arguments not exist 'imagem' ! and that give you error
// soo sloution is checking 'imagemOriginal'
function resete() {
    // soo here do your check     // if true call restCanvas for make canvas clear :)
  if (imgCarregada(imagemOriginal)) resetCanvas();

}

// this function using 'ctx' or canvas context for make canvas clean
function resetCanvas(){
    // fillstyle for select your draw color
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    // fillrect for draw with resloution :)
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}

// here just syntax better :)
function imgCarregada(x) {
  if (x === null) return false;
  else if (x !== null) return true;
}
```

Comment: @Ouchane_CC , I think will fill canvas with white "function resetCanvas()"

Comment: oh sorry you want to reset photo in canvas to normal colors not canvas him self
right

Comment: yeah ... reset to normal colors

Comment: ok i edit my code and i add function called resetIMG for you

Comment: this external file called SimpleImage.js do a lot of problem in your project
we need to delete this file for less problems

Comment: thanks @Ouchane CC for taking your time , but the problem was solved, it was "imagem". we dont need delete simpleimage, because if you look at html, you will see a script for it

Comment: thank you tow and i'am soo sorry for losing your time it's my bad too :)
if you  want anything you can text me on instagram ouchane.h :)